# KnockoutJS with IE8, occasional problems with Stringify?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, knockout.js, stringify

A number of our users are still on IE8.  Some of them occasionally are reporting problems when trying to post data to our servers (via a big button labeled "SAVE").

There is a script error that IE8 shows, which is: *Unexpected call to method or property access*, always pointing to the same line in the KnockoutJS 2.2.0 (debug, for now) library, line 450, which is as follows:

```
return JSON.stringify(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data), replacer, space);
```

The method in my code that is at the root of the stack trace where this happens is this:

```
self.saveSingle = function (onSuccess, onFailure) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.days(), function (day) {
            day.close();
        });
        var jsonData = ko.toJSON(self);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: applicationLocation + "/api/assignmentapi/save",
            data: jsonData,
            success: function (data) {
                self.status(data.Status);
                self._isDirty(false);
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.days(), function (day) {
                    day.clean();
                });
                if (onSuccess)
                    onSuccess();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                onFailure();
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });
    };
```

We do strip out a number of properties that are not necessary to our POST as we convert the object to JSON, using this approach: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html

```
OurType.prototype.toJSON = function () {
    var copy = ko.toJS(this);

    delete copy.someUnneededProperty1;
    delete copy.someUnneededProperty2;
    delete copy.someUnneededProperty3;
    delete copy.someUnneededProperty4;

    return copy;
}
```

*When* it fails, it fails consistently on the line

```
var jsonData = ko.toJSON(self);
```

Now here comes the real mess:

1. It's not consistently happening
2. It doesn't happen to all IE8 users
3. We can't consistently reproduce it
4. The structure of our model that we're serializing doesn't appear matter
5. The jscript.dll is the current version for IE8

Answer (score 2):

I was also experiencing this issue. Digging deeper I found a few things:

- It was only failing occasionally, I found this by running the code in the console
  [image]
- The code in the `data-bind` was trowing an exception except the message was being swallowed due to IE8 gobbling up the message when using a `try {} finally {}` block (without `catch`).
- Removing the try finally revealed a cannot parse bindings message.

When I started to get close to figuring out the issue (digging deep into the knockout code) it seemed to disappear in front of my eyes. This is the section of code it was failing on, catching the exception at the end of the code:

```
ko.utils.extend(ko.bindingProvider.prototype, {
    'nodeHasBindings': function(node) {
        switch (node.nodeType) {
            case 1: return node.getAttribute(defaultBindingAttributeName) != null;   // Element
            case 8: return ko.virtualElements.virtualNodeBindingValue(node) != null; // Comment node
            default: return false;
        }
    },

    'getBindings': function(node, bindingContext) {
        var bindingsString = this['getBindingsString'](node, bindingContext);
        return bindingsString ? this['parseBindingsString'](bindingsString, bindingContext, node) : null;
    },

    // The following function is only used internally by this default provider.
    // It's not part of the interface definition for a general binding provider.
    'getBindingsString': function(node, bindingContext) {
        switch (node.nodeType) {
            case 1: return node.getAttribute(defaultBindingAttributeName);   // Element
            case 8: return ko.virtualElements.virtualNodeBindingValue(node); // Comment node
            default: return null;
        }
    },

    // The following function is only used internally by this default provider.
    // It's not part of the interface definition for a general binding provider.
    'parseBindingsString': function(bindingsString, bindingContext, node) {
        try {
            var bindingFunction = createBindingsStringEvaluatorViaCache(bindingsString, this.bindingCache);
            return bindingFunction(bindingContext, node);
        } catch (ex) {
            throw new Error("Unable to parse bindings.\nMessage: " + ex + ";\nBindings value: " + bindingsString);
        }
    }
});
```

But yea, it stopped becoming reproducible so I came up with a hack that I tested and works earlier, just retrying the data parsing. So this:

```
data-bind="value: ko.computed(function(){return ko.toJSON(appViewModel.model()[0])})"
```

Became this:

```
data-bind="value: ko.computed(function(){while (true) { try { var json = ko.toJSON(appViewModel.model()[0]); return json; }catch(e){}}})"
```

Yes, it's very yucky, but it seems to do the trick until our users no longer need IE8 or the Knockout issue is fixed.

Comment: Ok, that is yucky.  :)  We're past this now, by having instead creating our own toJSON methods directly in our objects.  The down side is that it feels wrong to re-implement something that should have been working, but since we now create our own, I no longer have to take the step of deleting properties that I don't care about.  Double edged sword, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if this will fix it, but you can use the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to go between JS and JSON:

```
var mapping = {
    'ignore': ["propertyToIgnore", "alsoIgnoreThis"]
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.toJS(data, mapping);
```

Taken from my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988220/how-to-exclude-certain-properties-from-knockoutjs-tojs/14988353#14988353)

I'd give this a try and see if it helps, as there's nothing obviously wrong in your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's IE8 users who are hitting the issue? [IE7 does not support JSON.stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326893/is-json-stringify-supported-by-ie-8). You'll need to include the [json2.js library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) to support IE7 and lower.

Comment: We include json2 for the IE7 users.  No IE7 user has reported a problem; only the IE8 users.

Comment: Interesting. Could it be that the IE8 users are actually running in IE7 emulation mode (IE page compatibility)?

Comment: Our QA staff is *sometimes* able to reproduce it, and it's in IE8 mode when they do.

Comment: Wow, that really is strange. If you include the json2 library for IE8 users, does it change anything?

Comment: It's actually included generically in our site scripts, but since it internally checks to see if JSON is defined, it limits the usefulness.

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind is, sometimes refreshing the page multiple times in IE results in IE automatically changing the page to compatibility view. You're sure that's not happening with your QA process?

Comment: While we've seen the mode change happen (thanks for the explanation!), the QA team is sporadically able to reproduce this without refreshing the page itself.